# Variable $data might have not been defined

Tags: php, laravel

Is seen like I have define the $data, but how come have this error?

```
    public function login(Request $request){
    if($request->isMethod('post'))
        $data = $request->input();

        if (Auth::attempt(['email'=>$data['email'], 'password'=>$data['password'],'admin'=>'1']))
        {
            echo "Success";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Failed";
        }
    return view('admin.admin_login');
}
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: "Undefined variable: data"

Comment: what does `var_dump($request->input());` return?

Comment: You are only defining `$data` on POSTs, but you are _using_ `$data` in _all_ cases.

Comment: PHP `if` statements can omit the wrapping `{` and `}`, but will only eval the first line after, so, as others have said, `$data` is only defined if `POST`, but attempted to access on `GET` (and others) also.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put brackets after the `if`

```
if($request->isMethod('post')) { //<--HERE
    $data = $request->input();

    if (Auth::attempt(['email'=>$data['email'], 'password'=>$data['password'],'admin'=>'1']))
    {
        echo "Success";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Failed";
    }
} //<--HERE
```

The way your code is, you have an undefined variable `$data` if the condition isn't true.

PS: You don't need to check if the request method is "post". A better way is to define in your routes if this accepted method is post or get.

Comment: nice catch, i totaly missed it